# CSS hover on all elements not working as expected

Tags: html, css

I have tried to add a hover effect to every element in the website but `*:hover` is not working.

I have tried different html tags, but only some will allow this hover to work, like the a tag in the example

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  border: solid .5px #dbdbdb;
}

*:hover {
  border: solid .5px #737373;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Example Domain</h1>
  <p>This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>
  <p><a href="https://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code example is working. Why do you want to do this? Adding hover to every element in the view is a very expensive, and pointless, operation?

Comment: What browser/OS are you using because on Windows10/Edge for me each element is showing a border when I hover over that specific element. Did you expect some other outcome?

Comment: I understand, I just tested it on safari and edge on Mac OS it doesn't work either way

Answer (score 1):

The reason your hover is not working is because it is not being applied to the elements that you think it is.

The elements that you are targeting with your CSS are not the ones that are being hovered.
This is because the :hover pseudo-class is not inherited; That is, if you apply :hover to an element, it will only affect that element and not any of its child elements.

In your case, you are targeting the * selector, which matches all elements. But, because :hover is not inherited, it is not being applied to the child elements.

To solve this problem, you need to target the child elements directly with your CSS. For example:

```
a:hover {
  border: solid .5px #737373;
}
```

This will apply the hover effect to all **a** elements.

Comment: So this means i have to add every tag an own hover so that this works?

Comment: I can't see why this makes any difference. If the parent is hovered, but the cursor isn't oveer the a element, then it still won't be hovered. This method doesn't seem any different from using * as far as a elements are concerned.

Comment: it is not about a elements, it is about every element in the page